# Do you know how combine bar and spline chart in fusionc chart?

Tags: jquery, charts, spline, fusion

I need to combine bar chart and spline chart using fusionchart api. Do you know how to combine bar and spline chart in fusionchart?

Answer (score 0):

I have been using [Fusioncharts](http://www.fusioncharts.com/javascript-chart-fiddles/?type=Combination--Charts) and have tried their Combination Charts many times, which has been very useful for displaying different data in a particular chart. Coming up to your issue Bar Chart is basically the horizontal bars in the charts, their data in the x-axis depends on the values of the bars, and when coming to Spline chart the data of the y-axis depends on the value of the line been created.

According to me it would be better if you try out a different Combination Charts, where [**FusionCharts**](http://www.fusioncharts.com/javascript-chart-fiddles/?type=Combination--Charts) have many options.